# Get the screenshot of a streaming video on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How can i get the screenshot of a streaming video on iphone. I tried several methods.

1. UIGetScreenImage() -> This is private. The app will be rejected if I use it.
2. UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 768));
       [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
       UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   ```
   The code above cannot take the screenshot of video layer.
   ```
3. MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
       initWithContentURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"myMovie.mp4"]];
       UIImage *singleFrameImage = [movie thumbnailImageAtTime:10 
       timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];

   ```
   The code above does not work on a streaming video.
   ```

What else can I try besides AVFoundation. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but maybe it's possible to look at the CALayer and save that as an image or read each pixel of it and save it to a image?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it will work, but have you tried using AVPlayer? It should give you access to AVURLAsset which you could pass to AVAssetImageGenerator.

```
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:yourURL];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:pItem];

//observe 'status'
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{ 
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        AVPlayerItem *item = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
        if (item.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
            AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *)item.asset;
            AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
            CGImageRef thumb = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.0, 1.0)
                                                      actualTime:NULL
                                                           error:NULL];
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Also you could try using renderInContext: on AVPlayerLayer.

Comment: Also add line:  imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

If played videos have different rotation.

Comment: make sure to CGImageRelease(thumb); (also in ARC)